# How exactly is a MongoCollection Immutable?

Tags: mongodb

I am referring to this [page](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/databases-collections/). Highlighted in Green colored block is

> MongoCollection instances are immutable

However I know that Documents can be added / updated to a `Collection`. So why do we call it immutable ? What are the properties of `MongoCollection` that makes it immutable ?

Comment: It's talking about the returned object instance from the Java Driver method, and not the "contents" in the MongoDB database. "Immutable" here basically means you cannot change this object instance to point at a "different collection" than the one used when you instantiated it.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. I hope this is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

> It's talking about the returned object instance from the Java Driver
>   method, and not the "contents" in the MongoDB database. "Immutable"
>   here basically means you cannot change this object instance to point
>   at a "different collection" than the one used when you instantiated
>   it.

Qouted from Neil's comment.